# Question about a passive form

Tags: passive-voice

I saw an example sentence, which is

**Staff members wear uniforms so that they are easy for customers to identify.**

In my opinion, it is clearer if 'to identify' changes to 'to be identified'. I wonder which one is more natural or which one is wrong? It makes me confused.

If the written sentence is acceptable, what about this sentence, which is

**Staff members were able to identify be customers easily.**

Thank you for considering my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are proposing to change the first sentence to

> Staff members wear uniforms so that they are easy for customers to be
>   identified

but that reverses the meaning — it now says that **customers** are easy to identify, not the **staff**. A better version of your sentence could be

> Staff members wear uniforms so that they can be identified by
>   customers

---

Now, your second sentence

> Staff members were able to identify be customers easily

Isn't grammatical. I suggest this version

> Staff members were able to be identified by customers easily